# How can I reinstall the Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) management software?

Tags: windows, intel-rst

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 on my desktop PC which has a RAID array set up on the onboard Intel controller.

The array is working properly, and I have the latest Intel RST driver installed, but I'm not seeing the management software that I can use to view my RAID' status and settings from within Windows.

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I install it? Every search only shows results for the driver itself, not the management software. The Intel Driver Update utility does not show any available updates.

Answer (score 1):

On the Intel website, they provide downloads for the driver only (typically used when installing Windows onto RAID if Windows doesn't already have the driver), and a download that includes driver + software.

I must have downloaded the driver only. Downloading the right one installed it alongside the current driver.

[image]